# Which TAG to use to cancel the job

Tags: android-workmanager

PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder has `addTag` method, `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, policy, periodicWorkRequest)` also has the TAG.

Question is which TAG to use in order to cancel all `MyWorker` task ? Will it be `MyWorkerTag` or `MySchedulerClassTag`

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder builder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                MyWorker.class, 
                PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        builder.addTag("MyWorkerTag");
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("MySchedulerClassTag", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [`PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder) and [`OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder) include a [`addTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#addTag(java.lang.String)) method that allows you to set a `TAG` that you can later use to identify a set of work request to observe or [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#cancelAllWorkByTag(java.lang.String)) them.

In the case of the [`enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(UniqueName, policy, workrequest)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%2520androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%2520androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)), the first parameters is a unique name used by WorkManager to identify each unique work and it is not related to the `TAG` assigned to the WorkRequest.

So, to cancel your worker you should use the `TAG` set on the WorkRequest using the `setTag` method:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder builder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            MyWorker.class, 
            PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .addTag("MyWorkerTag")
    .build();

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "UniqueName", 
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, 
            builder);

// Later on, when needed
WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag("MyWorkerTag");
```

More information are available on the documentation:

- [Cancelling and stopping work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work)
- [Hadling Unique Work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work)